# Problemas de cardinalidad en modelo entidad relación

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, relaciones, diagrama-er

Siempre tengo problemas con el tema de cardinalidad a la hora de crear los diagramas y mi duda es la siguiente:

Tengo 2 entidades, una **factura** y la otra **producto**:
Mi lógica es la siguiente:

- Una factura tiene a muchos productos
- Un producto puede estar en muchas facturas

Por lo que la cardinalidad sería muchos a muchos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**O también pensé esto**:

- Una factura tiene a muchos productos
- Un producto puede estar en una factura

Por lo que la cardinalidad sería muchos a uno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cuál sería la forma correcta?**

**¿Algún consejo para no confundirme en el tema de cardinalidad?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**¿Cuál sería la forma correcta?**

La forma correcta es como mencionaste en el primer ejemplo:

- Una factura tiene muchos productos
- Un producto puede estar en muchas facturas

**¿Algún consejo para no confundirme en el tema de cardinalidad?**

Solo recuerda que para que las relaciones existan deben haber llaves primarias y llaves foráneas, si se hace el modelo ER como en el segundo ejemplo entonces Producto va a tener de llave foránea id_factura, lo que provocaría que el producto quedara atado únicamente a una factura y no podrían existir entonces productos si no existen facturas.

Un ejemplo clásico de esto seria Pais y ciudad, en este caso ciudad tendría de llave foránea id_pais lo que provoca que no pueda existir ciudades si previamente no existe un pais y en este ejemplo una ciudad pertenece solo a un pais ya que la misma ciudad no puede estar en otro pais.

Las ciudades son únicas y no existen copias, si no hay copias quiere decir que una ciudad solo puede estar en un país a la vez.

En cambio los productos no son únicos por lo que hay copias, si hay copias quiere decir que hay varios y si hay varios pueden estar en distintas facturas.

Espero te sirva.